# Google Maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How to change the color of a google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE marker on mouseover event? I read about the setIcon method but i don't want to add a new image only to change the circle's color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method to change a particular property of an existing symbol.

You must retrieve the current symbol(`marker.getIcon()`) set the new property(for a circle this would be `strokeColor`), and use the modified symbol as argument for `marker.setIcon()`